# Is it possible to run multiple MySQL slaves on same machine with one master?

Tags: mysql

I have setup MySQL Replication between MySQL Master on 172.16.100.91 server and MySQL Slave on 172.16.100.40 server.

Now i want to configure replication with two slaves running on 172.16.100.40 server and one master on 172.16.100.91 server.

Comment: couldn't you just run a different instance of MySQL on a different port? Also, what would you gain from having 2 slaves as opposed to accessing the same DB with different user/permission settings?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do so..

For this you have to run multiple instances on the slave server.
using different port, socket file, data directory and cnf file..

Thanks

Comment: I have already configure multiple mysql server with different port,datadir, socket file but it give error when two slaves running simalteniously with one master.

Comment: below link has solved my issue that is auto.conf file is same on two slaves so master not identified to which slaves it has to replicate :http://www.technobits.net/articles/58051/beware-of-mysql-56-server-uuid-when-cloning-slaves/